# A tool for structurally merging XSD's?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm currently trying to derive the structure of a large number of XML files. I have generated XSD's from each one of them using XSD.exe, and as expected, they are different from each other at varying degrees.

I am looking for a tool that can merge these schemas into one "superschema" that works with all of these XML files.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: what if you try to merge your xml files instead and then generate xsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach could be that you merge all XML files into 1. There are diff/merge tools that support XML merging natively. Though if you have n XML files you will have to perform at worst n-1 merges, because those tools can usually merge only 2-3 files at once.

Some examples of those tools:

- http://www.altova.com/diffdog/xml-diff.html
- http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextCompare

After you have your "master" XML you can use XSD.exe to generate the "master" schema.

Comment: If there is a way to merge XML files without regard to different content (as opposed to elements), that may work. I'm particularly conscious about keeping maxoccurs to a minimum.

Comment: On second thought, I can just do the XML merge programatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how effective merging can be, since it would be easy to point out a couple of issues related to it; for e.g., assume same XPath (to a node) in two (or more) different XMLs; how should the merge work: keep both as sibling nodes; replace one with the other; make a list from text nodes (if applicable)? In my opinion, you end up dealing with lots of issues related to the merge itself, as opposed to just letting the XMLs speak for themselves.

There's a post [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816815/xsd-for-xmls-with-list-of-different-and-reorder-types) that is very simple, yet it shows one scenario that a merge approach wouldn't be able to handle: if the desired outcome is to have an xsd:choice. Merging content in one XML, would innevitably create a sequence in the output XSD.

I believe that unless you let the inference engine deal with multiple instances of XMLs, most likely it'll not be able to figure out a good starting model for you to take and eventually quickly tweak manually.

I figured out a solution for the scenario you're having, after running once too many into the problem of quickly wipping up XSDs where XML samples were used as models. Try [this tool](http://paschidev.com); there's an ***XSD from XMLs*** command in the *Tools* tab, the *XML* group. (I am partial, since I wrote it). I just tried it against the post I was referring above and, not surprising, it came up with the same structure. The generated XSD uses a Russian Doll authoring style, since the core engine is based on the [XmlSchemaInference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemainference.aspx) - in other words, don't blame me for that :)..

I am working on an improved version, so if you're interested after trying it out, drop me a line using the support contact info and we'll take it from there.