# XSD for XML's with list of different and reorder types

Tags: xml, xsd

Tell me please, how can I create xsd schema, which successfully validate the following xml:

**Valid XML 1**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <list>
    <typeA>
      <value>test string value 123</value>
    </typeA>
    <typeB>
      <value>test string value 456</value>
    </typeB>
    <typeC>
      <value>test string value 789</value>
    </typeC>
  </list>
</start>
```

**Valid XML 2**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <list>
    <typeB>
      <value>test string value 456</value>
    </typeB>
    <typeC>
      <value>test string value 789</value>
    </typeC>
  </list>
</start>
```

**Valid XML 3**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <list>
    <typeC>
      <value>test string value 789</value>
    </typeC>
    <typeC>
      <value>test string value 123</value>
    </typeC>
  </list>
</start>
```

**Valid XML 4**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <list>
    <typeC>
      <value>test string value 789</value>
    </typeC>
  </list>
</start>
```

**Not valid XML 5 with reorder types**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <list>
        <typeB>
            <value>test string value 456</value>
        </typeB>
        <typeC>
            <value>test string value 789</value>
        </typeC>
        <typeA>
            <value>test string value 123</value>
        </typeA>
    </list>
</start>
```

---

I wrote XSD, but it doesn't work for XML with reorder types (XML 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="typeC">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="typeB">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="typeA">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="start">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="list"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="list">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="typeA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="typeB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="typeC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

The solution should work for 5 different XML files, listed above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. When you say XML 5 is "not valid", are you saying that you want the schema to reject it as invalid, or are you saying that there is a problem because the current schema rejects it as invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="start">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="list" type="list"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="list">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="typeA" type="generic" />
        <xs:element name="typeB" type="generic" />
        <xs:element name="typeC" type="generic" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="generic">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This shcema doesn't make instance XML 5 invalid. (But on re-reading the question, perhaps the OP wants instance XML 5 to be valid? I've no idea.)

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes he wants it to be valid.. thats what his requirement is.